# Часть речи и синтаксическая функция

Tags: части-речи

Определите часть речи и синтаксическую функцию слов, присоединяющих придаточные в каждом предложении.

> Там реял дух земли,
>   Который в идеале
>   На небо возвели
>   И демоном назвали
>   (Пастернак)

- относительное местоимение, дополнение
- союз
- указательное местоимение, подлежащее
- относительное местоимение, подлежащее

Comment: Предложите свой ответ.

Comment: Который - либо относительное местоимение, либо союз. Я думаю, что в этом предложении "который" - относительное местоимение, дополнение. Хотя сомневаюсь на счет союза.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем примере "который" - союзное слово  (по синтаксической функции) и относительное местоимение (как морфологическая категория).

Comment: В задании необходимо выбрать один из четырех предложенных вариантов. Насколько я понимаю вы имели ввиду первый вариант?

Comment: Вы правильно поняли.